# How does re.sub work in conjunction with the pipe character in a python regex?

Tags: python, regex, pipe

I am trying to figure out how Python knows to remove the spaces on both ends of the string.  Here is the code I am referring to, which is the first step in my attempt to recreate the strip() function:

```
#! python3
#myStrip.py - I will be recreating the strip function in python
import re

def stripFunc(stringToStrip,character):
    
    if character == '':
        whiteSpRegex = re.compile(r'^\s+|\s+$')
        finishedString = whiteSpRegex.sub('',stringToStrip)
        return finishedString
        
    else:
        otherRegex = re.compile(rf'^{character}+|{character}+$')
        finishedString = otherRegex.sub('',stringToStrip)
        return finishedString
        
    
    
testString = ' Something with spaces on the ends '
finalR = stripFunc(testString, '')
```

The function performs exactly as I would want it to in this scenario, but I don't understand why, specifically, how the space at the end is removed.  I thought that this regex expression would, in order:

1. Look for a piece at the start of the string with 1 or more spaces, and proceed to sub in '', OR
2. Look for a piece at the end of the string with 1 or more spaces, and proceed to sub in ''

Instead what it seems to be doing is correctly is capturing the whole expression with the regex and subbing in the '' based on both pieces I included in my piped regex.

What am I missing here?  Shouldn't the pipe be grabbing and working with only the first piece of the string?

Comment: `re.sub` replaces all matches if you do not pass the `count` parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex will match the pattern on either side of the alternation symbol. Like you said, it will match the spaces at the start OR end of the line. But `re.sub` performs the substitution for all matches in the string. Consider " foo ". The space at the front is matched and removed. But then `re.sub` continues to search for other patterns in the string. The space at the end is found and is also removed.